# create column by combining index #, string

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe containing a column of strings.  I want to create a new column that combines the index number and the string column together in a list comprehension. The following code does this operation iterating in a loop:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'strings': ['string1','string2','string3']})
new_col=[]
for i in df['strings'].index.values:
    new_col.append(str(i)+','+df['strings'][i])
df['new_col']=new_col
```

Above code works but is slow.  How can I do this in a list comprehension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the index to string and add as usual (arrays of) strings:

```
df['new_col'] = df['strings'].index.astype(str) + ',' + df['strings']
```

Output:

```
   strings    new_col
0  string1  0,string1
1  string2  1,string2
2  string3  2,string3
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want **list comprehensions** then I would recommend using `zip()`

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'strings': ['string1','string2','string3']})
df['new_col'] = [str(y)+','+str(x) for x,y in zip(df['strings'],df.index.values.astype(int))]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   strings    new_col
0  string1  0,string1
1  string2  1,string2
2  string3  2,string3
```

Answer (score 0):

This will provide a new column with the index plus your string column

```
df['new'] = df.index.astype(str) + df['strings']
```

Comment: Please consider adding at least some explanation as though why this answer the question

Answer (score 0):

Reset Index and then by using the column to create the new column

```
df=df.reset_index()
df['new_col']=df['index'].astype(str)+','+df['strings']
```